# Does std:map Destructor call Key Destructors as well as Value Destructors?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, destructor

For example, does the following leak?

```
Foo ( )
{
   std:map<std:string, int> myMap;
   myMap[std::string("Bar")] = 2983;
}
```

I believe it does not leak but can't find specific documentation on this point.

Comment: Yes, it does destroy both the key and the value.

Comment: For reference, see [container.requirements.general], paragraph 3, in the C++11 standard.

Comment: @Ben, thanks, what paragraph number?

Comment: Did you mean what section number? 23.2.1 in the draft standard.

Comment: @Ben, It's paragraph 23.2.1.3. So I suppose the `std::pair` destructor calls both elements destructors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, map destructor `map::~map()` will call destructor for every key and value it manages and free memory.

**§ 23.2.1
   Table 96 — Container requirements (continued)**

```
(&a)->X() void 
the destructor is applied to every element of a; all the memory is deallocated.
```

Comment: Elements are `std::pair`. So destructing a `std::pair` destructs both `first` and `second`?

Comment: yes, it's just like normal destruction of a pair of key/value, destructor of key/value will be called accordingly. If any key/value is not destroyed and memory deallocated, it should lead to resource leak.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it certainly does.  This is pretty standard stuff in C++, and basically everything in the standard library and STL works this way--destructors are always called unless you're storing raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating any memory dynamically using `new`. All the variables are allocated on the stack. I can't see any memory leaking here.

Comment: `std::string` allocates memory on the heap, and its destructor de-allocates it.

Comment: Surely the elements within the map are allocated on the free store, not the stack.  Otherwise their lifetime would be...problematic.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Lifetime isn't the problem, it could be stored by-value in the map. The fact that there is no bound on the number of elements in a collection is why it allocates dynamically.

Comment: @delnan Yes, `std::string` stores its value on the heap, but the `std::string` reference itself exists on the stack in the example, does it not?

Comment: @Nikhil Actually, it doesn't, it lives in a node `std::map` allocates on the heap. But where it lives isn't important to this question anyway, as OP only asks whether its destructor is called.